# how to include "," comma in SystemVerilog Macros

Tags: macros, system-verilog

There are Argument that contain "," comma inside it for example num,val,int in one Argument.

For example,
`define ACTION_DO(num,val,int)

Which are actually meant to pass as one Argument only, is there any way to include the "," comma inside the code and wont get assumed by compiler as 3 Argument separately?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no good generic way to deal with a single argument containg commas in macros.  There are a couple of possibilities which might or might not fit in your usage mode:

1. Quoted strings, which are always treated as a single argument,
2. argument listed within parens or square braces. But in this case parenthesis and braces will be a part of the argument:

The following will work:

```
`define PRINT(A) $display A
... 
`PRINT(("a=%b, b=%b, c=%b", a, b, c));
```

It will be expanded to `$display ("a=%b, b=%b, c=%b", a, b, c)`

The following will **fail** in compilation

```
`define PRINT(A) $display("a=%b b=%b c=%b", A)
`PRINT((a, b, c));
```

because expansion `$display("a=%b b=%b c=%b", (a,b,c))` is syntactically wrong.